# Composable Entity Framework Queries on Navigation Properties

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, entity-framework-6, navigation-properties

I have an IQueryable extension method that I would like to use in 2 places:

1. DbSet
2. Navigation property

This query is defined as:

```
public static class TrainingModuleQuery
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Modules have to be exposed to the state or user group, plus be active.
    /// </summary>
    public static IQueryable<TrainingModule> ExposedModules(this IQueryable<TrainingModule> folders, int stateID, int userGroupID)
    {
        return folders.Where(m =>
            (m.UserGroups.Any(ug => ug.UserGroupID == userGroupID) || m.States.Any(s => s.StateID == stateID)) &&
            m.StatusID == (int)Status.Active);
    }
}
```

and is used like:

```
    public static IQueryable<TrainingFolder> ExposedFolders(int stateID, int userGroupID)
    {
        return ObjectContext.TrainingFolder
                            .Where(f => f.Modules
                                         .AsQueryable()
                                         .ExposedModules(stateID, userGroupID)
                                         .Any());
    }
```

However, when I try to run this code I get the exception:

```
LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.Linq.IQueryable`1[Data.TrainingModule] ExposedModules(System.Linq.IQueryable`1[Data.TrainingModule], Int32, Int32)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.
```

Is there any way I can define this query and use it both on a DbSet and on a Navigation Property?

Thanks in advance

Comment: What return type has `Ordered()` and what type has `f`?

Comment: Ordered() returned an IQueryable<TrainingFolder> so 'f' is also of type TrainingFolder.  However, I have removed Ordered() from  ExposedFolders() to simplify the problem.

Comment: Why do you have `AsQueryable()`? What will happen when you remove it?

Comment: I am using Database-First Entity Framework.  By default the navigation properties are of type ICollection<T> so AsQueryable() is needed to get the code to compile (however, it still throws at runtime).